# Unity - Animations - Animation Doesn't Flip Left/Right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have code that works for flipping the player to face the direction that it is moving upon the X-axis. However, since I have added animations, the animation will play, but will not flip in the other direction.

Notes-

1. I'm not accessing an Animator to run my animations
2. I created AnimationClip variables
3. I play my animations GetComponent().Play("Idle");
4. I do have an Animation component added to my player controller with
   fields for each animation inserted.

Code

```
 [SerializeField]
 private AnimationClip idle;
 [SerializeField]
 private AnimationClip walk;
 [SerializeField]
 private AnimationClip hop; // Alternative name for JUMP
 [SerializeField]
 private AnimationClip death;
```

5. The code I have below works perfectly, However, making a transition to Jump has proven difficult.

Code

```
  if (Mathf.Abs(player.velocity.x) > 0)
    {

        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Walk");
    }
    else
    {

        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Idle");

    }
```

6. The code below for jump DOESN'T play the animation:

Code

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && onFloor==true || 
    Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && onFloor==true)
    {

        player.velocity = new Vector2(0, jump);
        onFloor = false;
       // GetComponent<Animation>().Stop("Walk");
       // GetComponent<Animation>().Stop("Idle");
        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Jump");

    }
```

7. I tried to stop all other animations and only play the jump
   animation.
8. None of that worked. Why? And what would be a solution?
9. My animation clips will play but won't flip to the left.

Code

```
        faceRight = !faceRight;
        Vector3 Pscale = transform.localScale;
        Pscale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Pscale;
```

10. I have tried inserting the animation for walking inside the Pflip()
    which is what you're seeing above, a function that's called inside
    of a FixedUpdate().

[image: StateMachine]

I've tried to set up the Animator State Machine but all animations would occur at the same time. That's when I abandoned the Animator and decided to call my animations to play from code. I feel as though I've set up the state machine properly as far as my transition lines are concerned.

Ok, so I've set a Trigger for each transition line named "Activate". I revamped my code accordingly into this:

```
 private Animator anim;

 void Start()
 {
    anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
 {

 if (Mathf.Abs(player.velocity.x) > 0  && onFloor==true)
    {

        //ani.SetTrigger(walk.ToString());
        anim.ResetTrigger("Idle");
        anim.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else if(Mathf.Abs(player.velocity.x) == 0  && onFloor==true)
    {

        //ani.SetTrigger(idle.ToString());
        anim.ResetTrigger("Walk");
        anim.SetTrigger("Idle");

    }
```

However, this still doesn't fix my issues. For one, the animations do not play. Secondly, I cannot test to see whether or not my player will flip on the axis once playing.

I'm getting a mild error in the console during runtime that say's the animations don't exist. I made sure that all animations are on the states inside of the animator. I also made sure that none of the animations are marked Legacy.

Comment: So does your jump animation work or not? You say it doesn't in point 6 but you say the clips (which clip?) works in point 9. Your flipping code was taken from the Unity's example, which probably means that its the way you are calling it that is wrong.

Comment: @SwiftingDuster No, the Jump animation will not play. I thought it was because one of the other animations were playing and overriding the animation. Which is when I tried to stop the other animations from playing before running it. However, this did not work.

Comment: Ok, the code that works is the walk/Idle. The code that doesn't work is Jump.

Comment: Ugh.. I confused myself and you. All my code works. However, when I implemented the animations, the code still works, but the jump animation does not. Additionally, the player no longer will face left. The code I provided for flipping DOES work without the animation code attached. The walk and idle animations do work; however, the flipping part stopped working. Make sense? And sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I would recommend you to use Animator Controller. It will help you a lot to make transitions between one animation an another. Check this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimatorController.html If you face problems with the animator, let us know here, we will try to help.

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre - I added an image to my main post. I tried to setup the State Machine but coudn't get it to work properly, so I decided to use no Animator. Why are the transitions so difficult to use from code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question and comments.

*I've tried to set up the Animator State Machine but all animations would occur at the same time.*

This probably means you are setting wrong the transitions or the initial values in the State Machine.

My recommendation for you is to check this [video](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/player-character?playlist=17144) about how to use State Machine. IT belongs to a longer tutorial, but that video may be enough for your problem.

If you follow the tutorial you will see you need to create parameters of type boolean to activate animations from your script. So for example you will create one named `isWalking` which will be linked to your walk animation. Then from your code you can set that parameter to true or false with:

```
anim.SetBool ("IsWalking", walking);
```

This is an example of what you can try. But you will need to adapt it to your real needs:

```
bool walking = false;

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    // Animate the player.
    Animating();
}

void Animating (float h, float v)
{
    if (Mathf.Abs(player.velocity.x) > 0  && onFloor==true)
    {
        walking = true;
    }
    else if(Mathf.Abs(player.velocity.x) == 0  && onFloor==true)
    {
        walking = false;
    }

    // Tell the animator whether or not the player is walking.
    anim.SetBool ("IsWalking", walking);
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a try and I'll let you know if I run into any issues. I appreciate the suggestion! This looks good! I don't understand much about the state machine so your tutorial will be a gold mine of information! You are correct. The problem is that all the states try to activate at the same time and even when I set parameters of IsTrigger or SetBool. This is what's really confusing me. I don't understand why it's happening.

Comment: Apparently the issue with the player not flipping was directly correlated with the state machine running all states. Once I got the state machine operating properly, the rest of the code fell into place. I had to, as you suggested, make modifications to the code to suit my needs. However, you saved my cyber-designer life lol Great video, thanks for sharing!